# Starting service with non-primary constructor - passed variable is null onStartCommand

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a service with secondary constructor and variable in it (interface MyCallback). When from an activity I start service and pass a variable, I have a null pointer exception in callback.operate() in service. Why? Logging in the constructor is passed, so I have non-null callback variable. But in onStartCommand it's null...
In activity I implement interface MyCallback and start service:

```
startService(Intent(this, MyService(this)::class.java))


class MyService() : Service() {

    private var callback : MyCallback? = null

    constructor(callback : MyCallback) : this() {
        this.callback = callback
        if (this.callback!=null){
            Log.v("log", "callback not null")
          }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int):Int 
    {
      callback.operate() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass data inside `Bundle` do not create an Object of Service. remove constructor let it have default one only . Use `Intent` `startService(Intent intent)`  .. How are you currently starting this Service ?>

Answer (score 1):

> I have a service with secondary constructor and variable in it.

Delete the secondary constructor.

> I have a null pointer exception on callback.operate() in service

`startService()` will not use that secondary constructor. It is possible that *you* used the secondary constructor, but that is not a valid `Service` instance, and Android will not use it.

If you wish to have your service communicate with other portions of your app, you can:

- Use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.)
- Have your service talk to some repository singleton, which then supplies that information to interested parties (via callbacks, RxJava, `LiveData`, Kotlin channels/flows, etc.)
- Have the activity pass a `Messenger` to the service via an `Intent` extra, where the `Messenger` is tied to some `Handler` that the activity can use to receive messages sent by the service

Comment: Thanks! Now I use LocalBroadcastManager and I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Logging in the constructor is passed, so I have non-null callback variable.

`MyService(this)::class.java` is a [bound class reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11); it'll call `MyService(this)`, get the class of the result (which is `MyService`) and then throw the created instance away.

Then `startService` will create a new instance using the primary constructor. If you change logging to

```
if (this.callback!=null) {
    Log.v("log", "callback not null")
} else {
    Log.v("log", "callback null")
}
```

you should see first `callback not null` and then `callback null`.